# Windows Phone 7.5 - Bing Maps - Balloon like Google Maps

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, bing-maps, popup-balloons

I'd like to know if is there a way to draw a balloon like that from Google Maps using Bing Maps on Windows Phone 7 (Silverlight).

Answer (score -1):

Refer this [step-by-step tutorial](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-drawing-custom-pushpins-on-the-map-control-what-options-do-we-have) for the creating custom Pushpins on your Bing map.

URL of the Google 'Balloon' marker: [link](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/7/6/5/1308001441853739087google%20maps%20pin.svg)

Comment: This is a Google 'Balloon': http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2333/2070651645_3e7dd0d693.jpg